# Linking error using Visual Studio to build JNI dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker

I am a java programmer so excuse me for my knowledge on C++ world. I am trying to build a DLL for JNI stuff in my project; where the DLL refers to 2 other dlls with both `.dll` and `.lib` files available.

I searched and it seems I need to include the .lib file in the "Additional Library Directories" and I did so; Also I add the folder (container both `.lib` and `.dll` files) to the "Library Directories" under VC++ Directories item in the properties of the project. But when I am building the project I still receive warning from the linker saying the function implementation cannot be found.

A sample project is included from the DLL provider, where it's a win32 exe and they succeeded in building by just include the lib file in the project without adding to any of the directories; so I tried to do the same but it still doesn't work.

I checked my command line for linker is as below. Please someone kindly help me out of this.

```
/OUT:"F:\Projects\hf\MyProject\x64\Debug\MyProject.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"F:\Projects\MyProject\x64\Debug\MyProject.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"F:\Projects\MyProject\x64\Debug\MyProject.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"F:\Projects\MyProject\x64\Debug\MyProject.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\MyProject.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"RelativePathToLibFolder\customLib.lib" /LIBPATH:"RelativePathToLibFolder\customLib.lib" /TLBID:1
```

Answer (score 1):

Right. FYI - I found the problem of this. It's because the `dll` is a win32 dll but I have set the build configuration to x64. Just could the error message be any better, Microsoft ...